# How to upgrade RPM (not a package, the manager itself)

Tags: rpm

I am trying to install YUM and I need to upgrade RPM from 4.4.2 in order to do this. Could someone please point me to a guide for upgrading rpm to the latest version?

Do I have to install the latest version from source? Is these a concise guide for doing this when I already have RPM installed? 
Simply following the instructions in the INSTALL file for RPM give me an error './autogen.sh: line 7: autoreconf: command not found'

Comment: For what distribution?

Comment: The distribution I am using is Suse

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to download an rpm packet with the newest version of RPM and then upgrade (`rpm -Uhv <rpm-new-version>.rpm)`. You may need to download several more packages if the new version will require some packets that you do not have installed.

Comment: where can I find this rpm packet of the newest version of RPM. I dont see it anywhere at rpm.org